# I am getting no validation in my formulary.... asp.net mvc EF5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this viewModel class:

```
[Required]
     [StringLength(50)]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [EmailAddress]
     public string Email { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string MessageType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
```

And I have this code in my View:

```
@model Kekanto.ViewModels.DoubtViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Email)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)<br />
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)

@Html.Label("MessageType") 
<select  name="MessageType" id="MessageType">
<option ></option>
<option >Sugestion</option>
<option >Question</option>
<option >Complaint</option>
</select>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MessageType)

<br /><br />

@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Message)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Message)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)


     <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />

}
```

Despite the fact that some properties are Required I am getting no validation... I can send empty forms and I dont receive a message "This field is required"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript).  You might be missing some references to  the correct javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using client validation or only server side validation.

In order to fire the server side, you'll need to check `ModelState.IsValid` on your POST